# A word for someone who is left-footed but right-handed

Tags: single-word-requests

Most people are either right- or left-handed, or ambidextrous. This handedness is usually followed by the foot they use for kicking, meaning that a right-handed person is usually also right-footed.

Is there a word that describes someone who is right-handed but left-footed, or vice versa?

EDIT: I ask because I am right-handed and right-footed when doing something that involves my whole body (such as batting, archery, etc.), but am left-footed when it comes to kicking.  What does this make me?

Comment: "Most people are either right or left handed or ambidextrous" ... and some are just plain useless with both! ;)

Comment: Maybe *typical* - I am left everything except dealing cards and dialing phones. I think a few cross-sidings may be common.

Comment: And don't get me started on my childhood confusion when people tried to force left-handed scissors on me...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The terms *[cross-dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-dominance), mixed dominance, mixed [laterality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laterality), hand-confusion*, and *mixed-[handedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness)* are used to describe the use of different sides of the body for different things. Fans of board-sports might also be familiar with [*goofy-footedness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footedness).

In other words, the original poster could be described as *cross-dominant*.

Comment: Upvotes for references to cross-dominance & laterality. It doesnt completely describe me though.

Comment: @NWS That would mean that you are cross-dominant. See the list of cross-dominant people on the WP page.

Comment: A closer look at the page indicates this is correct.

Comment: "Goofy" just means you aren't riding the board facing the direction typcial riders (iow: Right-handers) do it. It's essentially the board version of "left-handed". It doesn't have anything to do with cross-dominance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a big issue with the accepted answer.

However, from personal experience, handedness in soccer (sorry for being an American here) is a bit different than when using actual hands.

I'm a lefty, but after a couple of years of play, I discovered that while I have more control with the left foot, I have more power with the right. Thus I'd usually shoot or clear a ball with my right, unless I'm going for placement (eg: an inside or outside of the foot shot). Dribbling is done with both feet. **A player who never touches the ball with one foot is probably not a very good player.**

Comment: Never apologize for who you are. :)

Comment: @tchrist - Well, I'm not really at all sorry of course. :-) However, there appears to be some law in the UK that requires them to insist on the [BE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English) meaning of "football" at any opportunity, and I find the ensuing discussion rather tiresome. I understand Brits like to apologize for seemingly everything, so I'm heading off that conversation in a way they might appreciate. Think of the parenthetical part as a small piece of BE inside an AmE answer.

Comment: Never apologize for apologizing when you darn well feel like it. =)

Comment: @CandiedOrange - Sorry about that. ;-)